# Cheapest way to index a large dataset on linux (preferably with sphinx)

Tags: database, linux, indexing, sphinx

I have a database with 150 million products, I would like index these using sphinx but only have ~2 GB of RAM, is there any feasible way to index all of this data using sphinx but staying under 2 GBs?

I only need to index Product name, Product description, and brand. Although I do have several attributes, but those wouldnt need to be searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ondisk_dict`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-ondisk-dict

That way only a small amount of data is loaded. Sphinx shouldnt need much memory at all.

As you using attributes, `docinfo`, could be used to control them
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-docinfo

Also reducing max_matches via the setLimit function should also reduce runtime memory usage.

Comment: Yes I was the poster on the sphinx forum too...do I better hardware to handle 100 million records (granted I have no users yet)? What is going to be the primary bottleneck pertaining to sphinx?

Comment: Well if you take the advice about keeping the dictionary on disk, and using inline attributes, then you only really limited by disk space. I/O might become a problem, small instances dont have great IO performance. But really, there is no substitute for just trying it!

Comment: Ok cool, I indexed 1 million, I am running sphinx on a separate instance than my web server. The first query (initiated from my web server) was slow then the following ones were fast. Does the search daemon go into sleep mode or something if not used for awhile? I am curious why there is this big of variation.

Comment: Not sphinx itself. But the OS will cache recently accessed files. So the indexes will end up being cached. These may be flushed if not used. There may be similar caching at hypervisor level, pretty sure EBS 'disks' are actully remote to the machine hosting your VM. And if there is really problems with memory, the VM may be swapping - which will slow things down considerably.

Answer (score 0):

check out this: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-rt-mem-limit

Comment: I will give this a try, thoughts on how much slower on-disk indexes are? I realize sphinx normal does the searches very very quickly, are on-disk indexes not feasible for web applications?

Comment: Changing rt_mem_limit - is more for how big a single disk chunk of a RT index is. This controls fragmentation of the RT index. In general it wont make a big difference to actual query performance. If you using normal index (built by indexer), rt_mem_limit has no effect anyway.